# How to install laravel on online website

Tags: laravel, frameworks

I am new to laravel and i tryed installing it but i didn't managed to do it.I ran command prompt exactly in the folder with the files of my website and i introduced this command :

> composer create-project laravel/laravel --prefer-dist

Laravel appears to be installed as every file is there so i managed to put it on my FTP(FileZila)

After that i tryed to go on mywebsite.com/laravel/ but this is what i get:

[image]

And this is what it shows me when i click on public:

[image]

Can someone please tell how to to correct this mistake ? or how to properly install laravel for my online website?

Answer (score 0):

Your laravel site is in http://yourdomain.com/laravel/public/

Maybe you should install MAMP or WAMP on your own computer and try Laravel there before actually deploying it to a life server.
You're going to meet lots of issues that you might want to solve on a faster connection to your code.

I hope that you are aware that Laravel is a framework, not a CMS.